# Blank spacing issue in email body when attached the file

Tags: php, csv, email, drupal-7

I am sending HTML php email file csv attachment.

Its working fine but the problem is that it takes blank space between the letter in mail body.

Here is my code for email

```
 $mailHader = '<div class="image" style="width:100%;margin-top: 20px;"><p style="text-align: center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.example.com"><span style="text-decoration:none"><img border="0" height="175" width="174" style="margin:0 auto; height: 80px; width: 80px;" alt="" src="https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/logo.png"></span></a></p></div></br>';

       $body= $mailHader."<table width='100%' bgcolor='#fff' border='0' cellpadding='20' cellspacing='0'> <tr> <td> <table class='content' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='margin-bottom:20px;width:100%;'> <tr> <td><p style='margin-bottom:20px;'>Dear Admin,</p><p style='margin-bottom:20px;'>Here are the membership report for users</p><p style='margin-bottom:20px;'>Please find the attached csv file.</p></td></tr></table><table class='content' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='width:100%;'> <tr> <td><p style='margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;'>All the best,</p></td></tr></table> </td></tr></table>";  

send_csv_mail($body,$to,$from);

function send_csv_mail($body,$to,$from) {

    $subject = 'Report';
        // This will provide plenty adequate entropy
        $multipartSep = '-----'.md5(time()).'-----';

        // Arrays are much more readable
        $headers = array(
            "From: $from",
            "Reply-To: $from",
           "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$multipartSep"
        );

        // Make the attachment
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(create_csv_string())); 

        // Make the body of the message
        $body = "--$multipartSep\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1;\r\n"
            . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . "$body\r\n"
            . "--$multipartSep\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: text/csv\r\n"
            . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
            . "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Website-Report-" . date("F-j-Y") . ".csv\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . "$attachment\r\n"
            . "--$multipartSep--";


        // Send the email, return the result
        return @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));

}

    function create_csv_string() {
    // my custom function to generate csv file
    }
```

It send me following email

Dear Admin,
Here are the membership report for users
Please **fi nd** the attached csv file.

All the **be st**,

It creating spacing between letters (like be st, fi nd etc)

Any Idea?

Comment: i think your problem is not in the send function but in the body variable that you pas to it

Comment: It's best show the `$body` variable as well your shown code is ok it seems.

Comment: Ok @sand , i have updated my question.

Comment: try changing charset=ISO-8859-1 to utf 8 charset

Comment: @Viswanath Polak I tried it but it's not working for me

Comment: can you var_dump $body and check what is in the string exactly.